# How to bypass proxy using apache (without using curl)?

Tags: php, proxy, curl

I want to get the content of some site across the proxy using php.  Instead of using curl , i want to do proxy authentications at Apacle level. So that there is no need to change the existing code.

Anyidea please ...

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do, and if possible show some code. You are mixing three or four technologies here that have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html)